# Two way binding in Angular without Input

Tags: angular

I have a class ObjectComponent which holds some data:

```
@Injectable()
export class ObjectComponent{
data: any;
....
...
}
```

And I have another Component ObjectViewComponent:

```
export class ObjectViewComponent{
    data: any;

constructor(
  @Inject(forwardRef(() => ProposalComponent)) public parentObject:ProposalComponent)
  {
    this.data=this.parentObject.data;
  }
```

As you see I want to access the data from the parent component (since they are loaded from another server and I want to avoid 2 http request). Since the ObjectViewComponent is created using router functionality I cannot pass the data from parent to child using Input.

This all works fine so far but there is no 2-way binding between the data in the ObjectViewComponent and the ObjectComponent. So whenever I change the data in ObjectViewComponent it will not change the data in ObjectComponent and vice versa. Any ideas how to achieve 2-way binding between both components? I am not very experience with Angular - I played a little bit with services etc. but I failed to achieve the 2-way binding in this example. I also checked stackoverflow none of the examples there worked for me.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: use Subjects(http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) for this sort of scenarios

Comment: Checked your link but this is for angularjs not angular 2/4? Can you also be a little bit more specific what I am doinmg wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a service and fetch the data there, say in the `service.ts` file and create a Subject from that data.

```
    data:CustomClass;
    dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject(data);
    fetchData(){
      //////fetch the data
      setData(fetchedData)
    }

    setData(data){
      this.data = data;
      dataSubject.next(data)
    }
```

Now in all the components where you want to get notified, subscribe the subject as

```
this.service.dataSubject.subscribe({
                next: (data) => {
                    /////this will be called 1. on first subscribe 2. on subsequent calls to setData() method in service;
                }
            })
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, I just build a service and it works. Not 100% - but I found some workarounds to make to make it working. Thanks you!