# Angular - how to get S3 bucket contents as Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rxjs

How do I structure a service method in Angular4 to make an s3.listObjects call to return the contents of an S3 bucket as an Observable?

Here's what I'm trying at present, failing miserably:

```
public loadFilesFromS3(): Observable<any[]> {

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket-name',
      Prefix: 'prefix-name'
    };

    return (
      s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          return(data);
        }
      })
    )

  }
```

Just completely stuck on this for the moment!  :-|

Comment: you can use subject(http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) as well

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how that comment is helpful.

Comment: subjects acts as an observable as well as an observer, check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953369/two-way-binding-in-angular-without-input/46954594?noredirect=1#comment80878481_46954594

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some homework here's what I came up with.  Seems to work well:

```
private tracksListSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public tracksList$: Observable<Track[]> = this.tracksListSubject.asObservable();

public loadTracksFromS3() {

    console.log('loading tracks from S3...');

    this.authenticate();

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {
      Bucket: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME
    };

    s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error!', err);
      }

      const raw = data.Contents;
      const tracks: Track[] = [];
      raw.forEach((item) => {
        tracks.push({
          id: item.ETag,
          title: item.Key,
          url: config.AWS_BASE_URL + item.Key,
          size: Math.round(item.Size / 1024 / 1024 * 10) / 10
        })
      });

      console.log(tracks.length, 'tracks loaded');
      this.tracksListSubject.next(tracks);
    });

  }
```

Then in other components I can just inject this service and subscribe to the `tracksList$` property on it.  Every time I modify the list of tracks inside the service, I issue `this.tracksListSubject.next(newTracksList)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Observable.bindNodeCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) function to convert the `s3.listObjects` function from a node style callback to a function that returns an `Observable`.

```
const listObjectsAsObservable = Observable.bindNodeCallback(s3.listObjects.bind(s3));
```

Note that as shown above you need to bind the s3 object to the function, to tell it that s3 is `this`. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Then you can use it as follows:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: config.AWS_BUCKET_NAME
};
listObjectsAsObservable(params)
  .subscribe({
    next: (response) => console.log(response),
    error: (err) => console.log(err)
  });
```

Comment: That does look like a winner, but at present when I go to implement this approach the line `const listObjectsAsObservable = Observable.bindNodeCallback(s3.listObjects.bind(s3))` gives me an error of `Property 'bindNodeCallback' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'`.

Comment: @twosouth Have you imported the `bindNodeCallback` function? Try adding the following import statement `import 'rxjs/add/observable/bindNodeCallback';`